# Stats query on Date crashes on DataStax Enterprise 2.2

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I'm getting a crash when trying to use StatsComponent in a query on a field of type "date" with an instance of DSE 2.2. It appears to be a bug. When I do a query like

`http://my_host:8983/solr/my_core/select?q=*:*&stats=true&stats.field=some_date`

I get an HTTP 500 error. Looking at the server logs, I see the stack trace below. It's trying to parseDouble my date string, which is clearly wrong.

This query works fine on Apache Solr 4.4. Is it a known bug / does anyone have a solution?

P.S.
I went looking around in the Apache Solr SVN repo to try and find the revision DSE 2.2 is based on which caused this stack trace. Does anyone know what version of Solr was forked?

Stack trace:

ERROR [http-8983-13] 2013-09-19 18:08:54,938 SolrException.java (line 114) java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2013-01-08T07:26:15Z"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SimpleStats.getFieldCacheStats(StatsComponent.java:281)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SimpleStats.getStatsFields(StatsComponent.java:234)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SimpleStats.getStatsCounts(StatsComponent.java:208)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent.process(StatsComponent.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1460)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:353)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.CassandraDispatchFilter.execute(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:248)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.CassandraDispatchFilter.doFilter(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSE 2.2 includes a much older version of Solr, if possible I would suggest upgrading to a newer version of DSE.